# I am unable to create a folder for my app within my external storage

Tags: android, file, mkdirs

In the beginning the code was working perfectly. But when I deleted the file from my internal storage to test the code it stopped working and every time it is returning '**false**' from the ***mkdirs()*** function.

I reinstalled the app several times, cleared caches but it is still not working. I have also granted the permission to write in external storage.

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My App/Media/Images/Saved Images");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    boolean b=direct.mkdirs();
    System.out.println("Value"+b);
}
```

Comment: your title says `internal`, while the code says `external` -- which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. In API 29 the getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated. 
Instead of that I used

```
File direct=new File(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath()+"/My App/Media/Images/Saved Images");
```